# MonoTouch.Dialog: GlassButton in Section

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uibutton, monotouch.dialog

I have a standard `DialogViewControler` which adds a `Section` with a View as the constructor:

```
Section sec = new Section (new LogoHeaderView (320, 87));
```

In the `LogoHeaderView` I add a MT.Dialog GlassButton

```
        btnContact = new GlassButton (frameContact);    
        btnContact.SetTitle ("Contact", UIControlState.Normal);
        btnContact.NormalColor = Settings.ButtonNormalColor;
        btnContact.HighlightedColor = Settings.ButtonHighlightColor;
        btnContact.Tapped += (obj) => {};
        btnContact.Enabled=true;
        AddSubview (btnContact);
```

The view renders nicely, however the button is not clickable and the `Tapped` event never activates. It's like it's not enabled?

How do I get a `GlassButton` to appear in a View in a Section and work like a button?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me. However if your `GlassButton` is outside your `UIView` limits it won't receive the tap events (it's a `UIView` thing not a `GlassButton` issue).

E.g. This does not work

```
        UIView view = new UIView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 200, 10));
        view.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;
        GlassButton gb = new GlassButton (new RectangleF (10,10,100,100));
        gb.SetTitle ("Contact", UIControlState.Normal);
        gb.Enabled = true;
        gb.Tapped += delegate {
             Console.WriteLine ("hello");
        };
        view.AddSubview (gb);
```

but change the first line to:

```
        UIView view = new UIView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 200, 200));
```

and you'll be able to click the button.

Comment: Ah, the fact that it rendered threw me for a loop. That did it.